# Cannot create a relationship when using two FK

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using `EF` in my `ASP.Net Core` application and I'm trying to associate an `UserNotification` table to my `User` table. These are the tables structure:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual UserNotifications { get; set; }
}

public class UserNotifications
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Sender")]
    public string SenderId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }      

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

What I did is create a `ForeignKey` of `UserNotifications` which I'm going to store all the notifications that the `User` has reiceved.

Inside the table `UserNotifications` I created two `FK` for `User` and `Sender`. Essentially I want store the `Id` of the `User` that has reiceved the notification, and the `Id` of the `User` that has sent the notification (`Sender`).

Inside the `OnModelCreating` I also defined the following logic:

```
builder.Entity<UserNotifications>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(n => n.Id);
    entity.HasOne(u => u.User)
          .WithOne(u => u.UserNotifications)
          .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.Id);

    entity.HasOne(u => u.Sender)
          .WithOne(u => u.UserNotifications)
          .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.Id);
 });
```

When I type the following building in the `console`:

```
add-migration InitialMigration -context MyAppContext
```

I get:

> Cannot create a relationship between 'User.UserNotifications' and 'UserNotifications.Sender', because there already is a relationship between 'UserNotifications.User' and 'User.UserNotifications'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.

I'm a newbie of `EntityFramework` so I don't know how to fix this, someone could explain what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is `public virtual UserNotifications { get; set; }`?

Comment: I think is a collection, the property name is in plural, but let's wait @Rockj responds

Comment: I think what @IvanStoev means is that the property is missing either the type or the name...

Answer (score 20):

The model you are describing represents **two** one-to-many relationships between the `User` and `UserNotifications` (btw, the entity should be named `UserNotification`) entities. Each EF relationship can be mapped to 0 or 1 unique navigation properties at each side.

You already have **two** `User` and `Sender` reference navigation properties (and corresponding FKs) in `UserNotifications`. What you need is **two** corresponding collection navigation properties in `User`:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserNotifications> ReceivedNotifications { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserNotifications> SentNotifications { get; set; }
}
```

and map the with fluent API:

```
builder.Entity<UserNotifications>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(n => n.Id);

    entity.HasOne(n => u.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.ReceivedNotifications)
        .HasForeignKey(n => u.UserId)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    entity.HasOne(n => n.Sender)
        .WithMany(u => u.SentNotifications)
        .HasForeignKey(n => n.SenderId)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
 });
```

Note that since such model introduces the so called *multiple cascade paths*, you need to turn at least one of the cascade delete off and handle it manually.

Comment: `DeleteBehavior.Delete` is now no longer available. What would you use in place?

Comment: @Jack I don't think it even existed, my typo. The option is `Cascade`.